# popup window containing two views to make a call

Tags: android, android-intent, call, popupwindow

[I want to make like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUvYn.png) 
when i press this cardview the popup window should be displayed as shown in figure

this is the card view that is to call the popup window

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/lime_green"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/order"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/order_now" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/order"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Order now"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: you will have to create a dialog,read more on using custom Dailog Fragments

Comment: how can i create a dialog

Comment: try searching this on google, "how to create a custom dialog box in android",Dialog creation is a long and delicate process, so u need to read on how to handle a dialogs lifecycle.No body on stack will give u code that u can copy paste for this,so reading will be ur best option.I m helping u out here,and solutions are not always code,sometime they are in form or recomendations also,welcome to stack